# Items using float are not lining up properly

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the html page below with in-line css. (Doing in-line right now while I fiddle with it to keep from having to flip between files). I'm trying to get the ViewBag.Title and the button items to be on the same line. I want the Title on the left side of the page and the button items on the right side of the page. Currently they are on the correct sides of the page, but the buttons are higher than the page Title instead of being on the same line.

```css
/*#region*/

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.web-header {
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 0, #000 0 -1px 0;
  line-height: 3em;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #339900;
}
.logo-image,
.home-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 7px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.home-image {
  max-width: 250px;
}
.clear-fix:after {
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
body {
  color: #333;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  overflow: auto;
  background-image: url("../Images/GreenBackGround.jpg");
}
#body-content {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.box-effect {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 90%;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#follow-icons {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  float: right;
}
.content-align {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/*#endregion*/

/*#region*/

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
h5 a:link,
h5 a:visited,
h5 a:active {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*#endregion*/

/*#region*/

.rmm {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.rmm a {
  color: #ebebeb;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list,
.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.rmm ul {
  display: block;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
/* sublevel menu - in construction */

.rmm ul li ul,
.rmm ul li ul li,
.rmm ul li ul li a {
  display: none !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  width: 0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;
  margin: 0px -3px 0px -3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
  background-color: #444444;
  border-left: 1px solid #555555;
  background-image: url('../Images/BorderImages/graphite-menu-bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
  background-image: url('../Images/BorderImages/graphite-menu-bg-hover.png');
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
  width: 95%;
  background-color: #555555;
  min-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
  display: block;
  height: 36px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('../Images/BorderImages/graphite-menu-bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 8px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  width: 24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
  background-color: #444444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
  border-top: 1px solid #444444;
}
/* MINIMAL STYLE */

.rmm.minimal a {
  color: #333333;
}
.rmm.minimal a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-main-list li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;
  margin: 0px -3px 0px -3px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled {
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 36px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-controls {
  display: block;
  height: 36px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-title {
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 7px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button span {
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #333333;
  width: 25px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  color: #333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
  border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}
/*#endregion*/

/***About and Current Styles****/

.products {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.products a {
  color: #000;
}
/*#region*/

@media (max-width: 350px) {
  #follow-icons {
    display: none;
  }
  .home-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .my-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 502px) {
  #follow-icons {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #home-table {
    float: left;
  }
  .home-image {
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 733px) {
  .sTableInfo {
    display: none;
  }
  #sTableImage {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 733) and (max-width: 912px) {
  #sponsor-div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #sponsorTable {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 775px) {
  #tournamentTable {
    display: none;
  }
  #tourneyNotifications {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 776px) {
  #tourneyNotifications {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 913px) {
  #sponsorTable {
    width: 740px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 913px) {
  .VidCol1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .tTableLocation {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1003px) {
  .tTableEntries {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*#endregion*/
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div>
    <h1 style="float: left">Patients</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="rmm" style="float: right; display: inline-block">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="NewItem">New Patient</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="DeleteLink">Delete Patient(s)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="products">
</div>
```

Comment: class="rmm" refers to css that makes the buttons look a certain way.

Comment: Add the relevant HTML and CSS to the snippet.

Comment: You can add CSS to push down the links x amount of pixels, or work that `vertical-align` property.

Comment: This is likely due to the default styling of the `h1` element.  It likely has default margin in most (or all) browsers.

Comment: Yep, it was the margin. I specified margin-top: 0; and now everything is on the same line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-top:3px` to class rmm.

see http://jsfiddle.net/ndyqqxxw/2/

Comment: I made the `h1` `margin-top: 0;`. margin-top fixed it though. Ill accept the answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this out  codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myWjzx

CSS

```
.title {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#d7d7d7;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
.rmm {
  background:#a7a7a7;
  width:auto;
  padding:0px 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  float:left;
  margin:0px 12px;
}
```